# Trying to run maven from ant using maven-ant-tasks-2.1.3.jar and it fails

Tags: maven-ant-tasks

As per the instructions from http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/installation.html, I downloaded the jar, added it to ANT_HOME/lib and ANT classpath, but it fails loading the classpath:

[image: Error]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: just realized that Image is too small, let me put the error below:BUILD FAILED
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: fFeatures
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)

Answer (score 1):

`<path id="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" path="lib/maven-ant-tasks-2.1.4-SNAPSHOT.jar" />`
  `<typedef resource="org/apache/maven/artifact/ant/antlib.xml"
           uri="antlib:org.apache.maven.artifact.ant"
           classpathref="maven-ant-tasks.classpath" />`

Did the trick

Comment: Download link is a little bit hidden - so here's the link to the repo:
[https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/maven/maven-ant-tasks/](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/maven/maven-ant-tasks/)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not the trick for me. Getting still the same error even with latest snapshot 2.1.4!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an old Xerces JAR file in your CLASSPATH or in the Ant 'lib' directory, which doesn't match. I had the same issue with a very old project and I solved it by deleting that JAR file.